# How to trigger SelectTemplate / How to use ContentTemplateSelector

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate

When using DataTemplateSelector in a WPF application, what kind of user action would trigger DataTemplateSelector.SelectTemple? And what is passed into "object item"?

```
public class ProductTypeTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate OrangeTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate AppleTemplate { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item,
      DependencyObject container)
    {
        string product_type = (string)item;
        if (product_type == "orange")
            return OrangeTemplate;
        else
            return AppleTemplate;
    }
}
```

Question closed. Updated the title to help other rookies like me search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say your second `TabItem` needs to show the updated `Content` depending on the selection. You can place `ContentControl` in it and bind its `Content` to the property on VM/code-behind which is tracking the `SelectedItem` of `DataGrid`. I am sure you would have bound the `SelectedItem` of your `DataGrid` of Tab1 to the property on your ViewModel/code-behind. Let's say that property is `SelectedType` and is of type `string` (as apparent from your question).

Now you just need to bind your `ContentControl` to this property and apply ContentTemplateSelector:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding DataContext.SelectedType, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}" 
                ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource myTemplateSelector}"/>
```

Here your VM/code-behind containing `SelectedType` property should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and should raise property change for `SelectedType`.

Answer (score 0):

Some controls ([`ItemsControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplateselector.aspx) for instance) expose a property that allows you to specify a DataTemplateSelector.

When the control is rendered, `SelectTemplate` is called for each items in the control. The `item` parameter is the templated object itself, which will vary depending on the control. Iit could be a cell in a grid, or an item in a list for example.

So in conclusion you don't need to trigger it, the method will simply be called by the control.

In the same idea, there are also [`ContentTemplateSelector`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.contenttemplateselector.aspx)s

Comment: Thanks Vache! I think ContentTemplateSelector might be what I actually need. Basically, I have a Datagrid on Tab1, and when I select one row, I want Tab2 to present different contents depending on the "type" of the selected row. Could you give me an example how to implement this? I've been searching for the whole afternoon, but couldn't figure out.

Comment: Hmm you could bind `Tab2`'s `ContentTemplate` (or the `Content` itself) to the `DataGrid`'s `SelectedItem` and use a `Converter` to implement your logic. Though this is now a new question and you might want to post it as such!